# February CU for SharePoint Server 2010 (KB 2597150) web front end issues

Tags: cumulative-update

I've installed (KB2597150) on my app server and my two web front ends.

After doing so, I've rebooted all servers and continued with running the SharePoint Configuration Wizard as administrator.  However this fails with the following:

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 Installed Across Server Farm 
 Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Core

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5002)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft SharePoint Portal

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5002)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft User Profiles

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5002)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft Shared Components

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5002)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft Word Server English Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6115.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 PerformancePoint Services for SharePoint

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 1033 Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6117.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft Excel Services Components

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6115.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft Document Lifecycle Components

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6116.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1 
 Microsoft Access Services Server

Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150) (14.0.6116.5000)
 Missing on webfrontend2
Missing on webfrontend1

I've also tried using powershell...and I get this result:

The following is missing on webfrontend2:
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)

The following is missing on WebFrontEnd1:
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)
Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2597150)

I have tried to reinstall the patch and get these results:

"There are no products affected by this package installed on this system.

Help Please,

Thanks,

Justin Wyatt

Comment: confirm SP1 is installed?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the Timer Service on the WFE(s).  That will re-register the installed products with the Config database.

Comment: All servers have been restarted multiple times...thus restarting the SharePoint 2010 Timer service.  I assume this is the one you are referring to?

Comment: I've actually had to specifically restart the Timer Service even after restarting the server(s) to resolve this.

Comment: I've tried this as well. Still no love. Also, if I open control panel -> programs and Features -> installed updates:  KB2597150 shows as installed.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to clear the Configuration Cache (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx) and see if it recognizes the products after the cache repopulates.  Look for timer cache related errors in the ULS logs as well.

Comment: Restarting the Timer Service did it for me too ! Thanks a lot !!